# ASP.NET EF with class library

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I created a class library which is going to have my database model with DB first approach. I am using the Northwind database.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<NorthwindContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("NorthwindContext"));
        });
}
```

In this method in asp.net project it tells me that the `NorthwindContext` is not convertible to `DBcontext` but the class inherits from it:

> Error CS0311
> The type 'NorthwindDal.NorthwindContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext(IServiceCollection, Action?, ServiceLifetime, ServiceLifetime)'.
> There is no implicit reference conversion from 'NorthwindDal.NorthwindContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.

If I don't use the `AddDbcontext` and try to run the project, it just tells me that it cannot find the connection string for the database.

The context is auto created and it inherits from the `DBcontext` as well.

I think its probably because I try to use the class library to do this but is there a way to use class library with ASP.NET?

Northwind Context

```
 public partial class NorthwindContext : DbContext
{
    public NorthwindContext()
        : base("name=NorthwindContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CustomerDemographic> CustomerDemographics { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Order_Detail> Order_Details { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Shipper> Shippers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Territory> Territories { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The error says that `NorthwindContext` doesn't inherit from DbContext. This has nothing to do with class libraries or ASP.NET Core. What is `NorthwindContext`? Post that code

Comment: `The context is autoCreated and it inherits from the DBcontext as well.` using what tools? Did you use the old EF tools instead of EF Core tools perhaps? Or trying to use a .NET Framework class library using EF 6 in a .NET Core project using EF Core 6 ?

Comment: I used the Ado.net EntityDataModel item to Create the model classes as well as the NorthwindContext maybe thats the wrong part?

Comment: Yes. The Entity Data Model was used for a short while when EF Classic was introduced but was hated by developers (including all C# MVPs) and abandoned once Code-first became popular. It required creating *two* mapping documents, when developers didn't even want to maintain the single mapping XML document used by NHibernate. The reason for this weirdness was even weirder - the original EF was what was left of the object oriented file system that was pulled out of Windows Vista. The EDM was never ported to .NET Core

Comment: Oh okey that makes sense. so How should I do a database first and use it with Asp.net?

Comment: Well, here is an example of how you  can implement a [`database first approach`](https://github.com/kironiitdu/UserActivityActionFitler#db-context-for-aspnet-core-database-first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your scenario if you would like to implement "database first approach" you could follow the below steps.

**Database Schema:**

[image]

You can [download `Northwind`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/master/samples/databases/northwind-pubs/instnwnd.sql) database schema from our official site as well. Just for reference.

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        
        }
```

**Note:** You can set any meaningful `connection string name` here in `DefaultConnection` as I have set this.

**DbContext class:**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Categories> Categories  { get; set; }
       

       

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Categories>().ToTable("Categories");
        }
    }
```

**appsettings.json:**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=YourServerName;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

**Controller:**

```
public class NorthwindController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MvcAttendanceDbContext _context;
        private IHostingEnvironment _hostEnvironment;
        public NorthwindController(IHostingEnvironment _environment, MvcAttendanceDbContext context)
        {
            _hostEnvironment = _environment;
            _context = context;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        
        {
            var categories = _context.Categories.ToList();
           
            return View(categories);
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCApps.Models.Categories>


<h3 class="card-title"><strong>Northwind Category</strong> </h3>
<div class="row">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;border:1px;padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px; margin-bottom:20px;box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;">
                
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><strong>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)</strong> </h5>
                    <p class="card-text">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</p>
                    <a asp-action="Details" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-memberId="@item.Description">Details</a> |  <a asp-action="EditMember" class="btn btn-warning" asp-route-memberId="@item.CategoryID">Edit</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>



    }
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To generate model classes and database context from an existing database you need to use ef tool scaffolding. You can do it using the command

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Your connection string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

You need the add reference following NuGet packages if you need to run the command.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```